# Concatenating file path

Tags: python, pandas

I have following paths and I want to concatenate them to make a final path:

```
path1 = \\ITSUSRAPADCON2\tm1\cons\grm_aspac\user_in\Manual Upload Current Plan\Archive

path2 = Dev Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_GrsSalesAdj.csv_02_11_2021_18_41_03_1862

final path = \\ITSUSRAPADCON2\tm1\cons\grm_aspac\user_in\Manual Upload Current Plan\Archive\ Dev Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_3069_WI2_2020_GrsSalesAdj.csv_02_11_2021_18_41_03_1862_In.csv

tried this:
final path = path1 + "\\" + path2 + "_In.csv"
```

gives following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
 '\\\\ITSUSRAPADCON2\\tm1\\cons\\grm_aspac\\user_in\\Manual Upload Current Plan\\Archive\\ Dev Finance GRM CONS ASPAC_Sales_3069_WI2_2020_GrsSalesAdj.csv_02_11_2021_18_41_03_1862_In.csv'
```

Comment: You are doing it properly, does the file exist?

And you might have an issue with the backslash - it needs to be escaped. Not sure if you do that, because of the current formatting.

You also have twice `.csv` in there

Comment: use [os.path.join()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/)

Comment: In the error message there is a space character before "Dev Finance". Is the directory name really starting with a " "? You may check the path2 variable for an unintended space.

Comment: @fieres it takes a "" after path1 otherwise it gives syntax error - r"\\OPCITSNAPADCON2.jnj.com\tm1\cons\grm_aspac\user_in\Manual Upload Current Plan\Archive\ " + file + "_In.csv"

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) function, like so:

```py
final_path = os.path.join(path1, path2)
```

This will be safe across operating systems that might use different path directory separators.